# Export @html.grid data to excel with pagination in MVC

Tags: jquery, pagination, asp.net-mvc-5, export-to-excel, grid.mvc

How to export data from @html.grid in mvc with pagination. It should be able to export data even after the filter is provided

i got the partial solution that is working for single page only. i need to export entire grid data
[grid.mvc use filtered Result in Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806174/grid-mvc-use-filtered-result-in-controller/35473090#35473090)